# How can I COMPLETELY remove malwarebytes from my PC?

Tags: windows-xp, malware

XP3.

I need to re-install malwarebytes, but when I do it still doesn't work because some files are not being removed.

What can I do?

EDIT: Soooo nice to have Malwarebytes back! Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To completely remove Malwarebytes Anti-Malware from your computer, do the following.

1. Uninstall Malwarebytes Anti-Malware as usual.
2. Restart your computer.
3. Download [mbam-clean.exe](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam-clean.exe) from the [malwarebytes.org](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) and execute it.
4. Allow `mbam-clean.exe` to restart your computer.

Sources:

- [Use mbam-clean.exe to completely remove Malwarebytes : Malwarebytes Support](http://helpdesk.malwarebytes.org/entries/20818461-use-mbam-clean-exe-to-completely-remove-malwarebytes)
- [UNABLE TO UNINSTALL MBAM - Malwarebytes Forum](http://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?showtopic=48511)

Comment: Good find, I saw this just after posting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the free version of [Revo uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/), set Hunter mode to ON, then reinstall malwarebytes. Hunter mode keeps track off all location, both file and registry, where software installs to. So this should give Revo the required information to uninstall correctly and fully using Revo uninstaller's "moderate" mode.